# Attempting to make a Move object in R - NA timestamp records

Tags: r, spatial

I'm trying to use my own animal tracking data (.csv) through the 'move' package but as I'm importing/projecting it, R gives me an error. Code below.

```
 df <- read.csv("Tracking_Data_CSV.csv")

N17042_move<-move(df$location.long, df$location.lat, time=as.POSIXct(df$timestamp,format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC"),
               proj=CRS("+init=epsg:32615"))   

**Error in validityMethod(as(object, superClass)): There are NA timestamps records
```

I have made sure that there are no NA time stamps within my data. I have no clue whether the problem lies within the data or within the code itself. I will appreciate any help with this. I include a snippet of the data below just to get a sense of the format.

```
  individual.local.identifier       timestamp location.long location.lat
1                      N17042  1/10/2017 0:57      373986.9      4426785
2                      N17042  1/10/2017 4:01      374027.8      4427036
3                      N17042  1/10/2017 9:01      373866.7      4427156
4                      N17042 1/10/2017 14:01      373878.0      4427167
5                      N17042 1/10/2017 19:01      373878.7      4427161
6                      N17042  1/11/2017 0:01      374010.6      4427233
```

Comment: Just guessing since I can't see all your timestamps, but it looks like your code says that your timestamps are formatted this way: `"%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"`, but your data does not have seconds and m/d/Y is separated by slashes, so the format is actually `"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are NA timestamps in your data, because your transformation into POSIXct is wrong.
Try this:

```
as.POSIXct(1/10/2017 0:57,format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
```

The output will be NA. Why? Because your format includes `/` not `-` and there are no seconds in your timestamp

Try this:

```
N17042_move<-move(df$location.long, df$location.lat, time=as.POSIXct(df$timestamp,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz="UTC"),
               proj=CRS("+init=epsg:32615"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my problem. I am completely new to POSIXct data formats so I am still figuring out the kinks.